# Are there no constants for javax.crypto.Cipher in Java?

Tags: java, encryption

I think a hardcoded String is error-prone, but I didnt found any Consants to set the algorithm for

```
Cipher.getInstance(...)
```

Am I blind or is there nothing out there?

Comment: Probably because this method is intended for transformations with a format of algorithm/mode/padding, like `getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`. Because they have internal structure, these are more naturally described and parsed as a string instead of a long list of constants for each possible combination. The method also works if you just provide an algorithm name without a transformation, but that does not seem to be the main usecase. Of course you can always create your own constants to prevent typos.

Comment: To answer your title rather than your question, there are constants for init opmode and unwrap keytype: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#field-detail